# I just installed latest Java SDK/JRE from Adoptium (version 17.0.1)... Where's the IDE?

Tags: java

First time ever using Java. I successfully installed the latest version from Adoptium, which is 17.0.1. I ran the HelloWorld program from the Windows 10 prompt without a hitch. Isn't there some type of IDE or something in the SDK? There's nothing on the windows start menu, and I can't find a JDK executable in the installed directory. What am I missing? Sorry for being such a noob!!

Comment: The JDK does not include any IDE. If you want to use one, you'll have to choose and install it yourself.

Comment: I see.... Thanks. Regarding Java not showing in the WIndows start menu/bar. Is that normal in these installations too?

Comment: A potential response from a fellow java noob (so I may be totally wrong). Re: Java not showing up in start menu/bar... remember - Java is a program to run programs written/compiled in java. Running java as a standalone program wouldn't do anything - so it not showing up in these places is good... what would you be running? Nothing... so why show up. Your computer has tons of stuff installed that you as an end user don't start up and run.